# How to setup user authentication in a Rails API backend and Vue as frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, devise

In this app I have Rails working as a backend API in which is consumed by a Vue app frontend.

I thought about using Devise gem, but as I don't have any view on Rails it won't work fine.

What would be the correct approach to implement the user authentication? Should I implement it on Vue?